# Cordova Android FileReader.readAsDataURL NOT_FOUND_ERR

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I am using both `cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova-plugin-media-capture` to capture video on iOS and Android. This implementation works perfectly on iOS, but does not on Android. I've traced the issue to the `FileReader` instance not being able to find the file that `cordova-plugin-media-capture` has recorded. Here is the block of code:

```
if (navigator && navigator.device.capture && window.cordova.file) {
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo((mediaFiles: MediaFile[]) => {
        if (mediaFiles.length > 0) {
            const mediaFile = mediaFiles[0];
            const type = mediaFile.type;
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL((mediaFile as any).localURL, (fileEntry: Entry) => {
                (fileEntry as FileEntry).file((file: File) => {
                    // "file" is a valid file with a local URL (cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/....)
                    const fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onloadend = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
                        console.log(event);
                        // event.target.error = 1 here which according to the docs is NOT_FOUND_ERR
                        success({ data: (event.target as any).result, type });
                    };
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }, (_error: FileError) => {
                    console.log(_error);
                });
            }, (_error: FileError) => {
                console.log(_error);
            });
        }
    }, (_error: CaptureError) => {
        console.log(_error);
    }, { limit: 1, duration: 10, quality: 1 });
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Here are the things I've tried:

1. Added `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />` to `config.xml`. Removed after this approach didn't work.
2. Added `<access origin="cdvfile://*"/>` to `config.xml`. Removed after this didn't work.
3. Ensured CSP includes `cdvfile:`
4. Ensured `AndroidManifest.xml` has both `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
5. Validated that the videos do in fact exist on the phone by browsing the Files app. The videos play just fine.

Testing on Android 8 with a Moto G6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After debugging `cordova-plugin-file`, I discovered that the reported `NOT_FOUND_ERR` was misleading, because it turns out there was a permissions issue.

[image: cordova-plugin-file error]

I thought it was sufficient to put the permissions to read external storage in the manifest, but it isn't. Android requires runtime permissions: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

After adding runtime permissions, the video capture process works as expected.

Comment: In my case, I also had to add "requestLegacyExternalStorage". Ex: <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" (...)><application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" /></edit-config>

Comment: @a432511 I added the runtime permissions, but with no luck ...How did you manage to see the actual error ?

Comment: hey brother, can you help me? how adding runtime permissions?

Comment: hey @Cesar, oh friend, thanks for success !!!! So awesome ahahah, I spent 2 days on this